# How to integrate a squared derivative for the swing equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

While going to some literature of Power System Stability for generators I came across a derivation of the power angle when a fault occurs from the swift equation.

The Swing Equation is:

$\mathbf{\frac {2H}{w_s}}\frac{d^2\delta}{dt^2}=P_m-P_e $

Where: 
$ H$ is the inertia constant, $w_s = 2{\pi}f$, $\delta$ = power angle and $P_m$ and $P_e$ are the mechanical and electrical power, respectively, and $P_e$ becomes zero at the fault moment.

From here is where I don't understand the maths that go behind to solve for the power angle $\delta_1$.

After a first integration the literature says to give :
$\mathbf{\frac {2H}{w_s}}\frac{d\delta}{dt}=P_mt+constant $

I don't understand how the $\int{\frac{d^2\delta}{dt^2}}dt$ was integrated to give $\frac{d\delta}{dt}$. Which property is this?

And finally after a second derivation it gives: 
$\mathbf{\frac {2H}{w_s}}\delta= \frac{1}{2}P_mt^2+constant $

Which after solving for delta yields:

$\delta_1= \frac{w_s}{4H}(P_mt^2)+ \delta_0$

Once again, how do you integrate $\int{\frac{d\delta}{dt}}dt$

I would appreciate if someone could walk me through the process or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus you get for any function
$$
\int_a^b f''(x)dx = f'(b)-f'(a)
$$
and
$$
\int_a^b f'(x)dx = f(b)-f(a)
$$
The right side should be integrated along the usual integration rules, however, you should only use the $P_e$ constant if it is zero. Also you should get a linear term after the second integration, what its coefficient is depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: but in the equations case , when integrating (d^2 delta / dt^2) is not a function of "t" , I understand it would be easier if it was (d^2 t / dt^2), also, I don't have the limits for evaluating a definite integral

Comment: The differential equation $f''(t)=c$ has the solutions $f(t)=a+bt+\frac c2 t^2$, a constant function is still a function.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand how I got from $\int{\frac{d^2\delta}{dt^2}}dt$ to $\frac{d\delta}{dt}$ and Pm*t

Comment: @Roy, integration "undoes" a derivative, no? So, if you integrate a second derivative, the result should be a first derivative.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int{\frac{df(t)}{dt}}dt=f(t)+C,$$

where $C$ is some constant, is the meaning of the integral sign - it is the "anti-derivative", i.e., it "cancels" the operation of differentiation.

Comment: the function I'm derivating is not function of t, so how do I proceed? thanks!

Comment: If a function does not depend on $t$, then its $t$-derivative is zero. This is seemingly not the case here, so you need to re-evaluate your basic ideas on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

the antiderivative of the derivative of a function $f $ if $f $. this is the first FOUNDAMENTAL THEOREM OF INTEGRAL CALCULUS.

$$\int f'=f $$
under some conditions.
$\frac {d\delta}{dt} $ is the derivative of $\delta $.